# Same bind for two commands in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, bind

So I'm trying to display two numbers using the same .bind ("):

```
def distance(event):
    dchain.configure(text = "distance = " + str(sqrt((x1-z1)**2 + (y1-v1)**2) -  30))

def gravitationalForce(event):
    fchain.configure(text = "force = " + str(pow(6.6710, -11.0)*(m1*m2/pow((sqrt((x1-z1)**2 + (y1-v1)**2) -  30), 2))))

win1=Tk()
win1.bind("<ButtonPress>", distance)
win1.bind("<ButtonPress>", gravitationalForce)
dchain = Label( win1)
dchain.grid(row=10, column=1, sticky=W)
fchain = Label( win1)
fchain.grid(row=11, column =1, sticky = W)
```

One seems to cancel the other one out, I tried using a  and a  this worked but now I'd like to add some more options and would like to know how this works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just wrap the functions into one. You can even do it inline with a `lambda` expression:

```
...
win1=Tk()
win1.bind("<ButtonPress>", lambda event: distance(event), gravitationalForce(event))
dchain = Label( win1)
...
```